# Cordova Splash Screen not displaying image

Tags: android, cordova

I'm developing an app using Cordova, and I'm unable to get the plugin "cordova-plugin-splashscreen" to work on Android (and I've only tested on Android).

I've installed the plugin using the cordova cli tool:

```
$ cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-splashscreen
```

And these are my config.xml-entries related to the plugin:

```
<platform name="android">
    ...
    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash.png" density="port-hdpi" />
    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash.png" density="port-ldpi" />
    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash.png" density="port-mdpi" />
    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash.png" density="port-xhdpi" />
    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash.png" density="port-xxhdpi" />
    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash.png" density="port-xxxhdpi" />

    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash.png" density="land-hdpi" />
    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash.png" density="land-ldpi" />
    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash.png" density="land-mdpi" />
    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash.png" density="land-xhdpi" />
    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash.png" density="land-xxhdpi" />
    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash.png" density="land-xxxhdpi" />
</platform>
...
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10000" />
<preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
<preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false" />
```

Instead of displaying the intented "res/screen/android/splash.png", the splash screen instead shows the default cordova icon or simply a gray empty screen.

Comment: Possibly related: I'm using the plugin "cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview" in the project aswell.

Comment: Try use also  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>

Comment: Tried adding this line, it had no effect.

Comment: Update: I tried removing Crosswalk to no avail.

Comment: Possibly related to this bug: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-9417

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Currently recommended solution:

Update cordova-android to version 6.1.0, where this bug is no longer present:

```
$ cordova platform rm android
$ cordova platform add android@6.1.0
```

Workaround, for the record:

"Solved" with workaround by manually replacing assets in:

```
platforms/android/res/*
```

Problem appears to be caused by the following bug: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-12077

Comment: no, that is not the bug, it's another bug and has been fixed in cordova-android 6.1.0, just update your platform and forget about your workaround

Comment: Fair enough, could you link the bug that caused the issue? I'd like to add it for documentation purposes.

Comment: Or better yet, add it as a response to the question and I'll accept it as the answer for the question.

Answer (score 1):

Complementing etoscnyl's answer, when using Cordova 6.4.0 don't type:

`cordova platform add android`

Instead, type:

`cordova platform add android@6.1.0`

Comment: Correct, I'll add this to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try edit your xml like this, for me it working. I had installed this package

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-splashscreen
```

And I use this xml, but different images only, this include yours

```
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10000" />
<preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true|false" />
<platform name="android">
        <splash src="res/screen/android/splash.png" density="port-hdpi" />
    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash.png" density="port-ldpi" />
    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash.png" density="port-mdpi" />
    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash.png" density="port-xhdpi" />
    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash.png" density="port-xxhdpi" />
    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash.png" density="port-xxxhdpi" />

    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash.png" density="land-hdpi" />
    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash.png" density="land-ldpi" />
    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash.png" density="land-mdpi" />
    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash.png" density="land-xhdpi" />
    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash.png" density="land-xxhdpi" />
    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash.png" density="land-xxxhdpi" />
</platform>
```

Try use  also `show()` in `deviceready` event , maybe it will help.

```
navigator.splashscreen.show();
```

Comment: Tried this, it did not work unfortunately. Are you using the Crosswalk-plugin aswell?

Comment: Update after edit: Tried adding navigator.splashscreen.show();, result is the default cordova icon displaying as splashscreen perpetually.

Answer (score 0):

Add this cordova **plugin** in your project

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-splashscreen
```

Splash Screen For **Android** :-

```
<platform name="android">

<splash src="res/screen/android/splash-land-hdpi.png" density="land-hdpi"/>
<splash src="res/screen/android/splash-land-ldpi.png" density="land-ldpi"/>
<splash src="res/screen/android/splash-land-mdpi.png" density="land-mdpi"/>
<splash src="res/screen/android/splash-land-xhdpi.png" density="land-xhdpi"/>

<splash src="res/screen/android/splash-port-hdpi.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
<splash src="res/screen/android/splash-port-ldpi.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
<splash src="res/screen/android/splash-port-mdpi.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
<splash src="res/screen/android/splash-port-xhdpi.png" density="port-xhdpi"/>
```

Spalsh Screen For **IOS**:-

```
<platform name="ios">
<splash src="res/screen/ios/Default~iphone.png" width="320" height="480"/>
<splash src="res/screen/ios/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" height="960"/>
<splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" height="1024"/>
<splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" height="2048"/>
<splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" height="768"/>
<splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" height="1536"/>
<splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" height="1136"/>
<splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-667h.png" width="750" height="1334"/>
<splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-736h.png" width="1242" height="2208"/>
<splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" height="1242"/>
```

After that add this into config.xml page

```
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
```